# Loop through list of tuples from a text file

Tags: python, list

I want to be able to loop through a list of tuples from my text file and display each tuple.

code:

```
with open('output.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

print(data)
```

output:

`[(21, 21), (21, 90), (90, 90), (90, 21)]`

what I want:

```
(21,21)
(21,90)
(90,90)
(90,21)
```

Comment: your file does not contain a list of tuples, *it is text*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ast` module to convert your string to a list object.

**Ex:**

```
with open('output.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = ast.literal_eval(f.read())

for i in data:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, just loop over data to get the tuples

```
for tup in data:
    print(tup)
```

Chances are that your tuple won't actually of the type 'tuple' but be a string instead,

you can use this function in that case,

```
def str_to_tup(s):
    tempS = s.split(',')
    return (tempS[0].replace('(',''), tempS[1].replace(')','')
```

I know this can be done more elegantly, but incase no one else answers :)